# No Data Inserted Into ElasticSearch with Olivere Golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I have changed my code so that it uses olivere package when inserting data into elastic search. This is the code

```
 // Get a snapshot of stats (always blank if not enabled--see above)
                    stats := p.Stats()

                    fmt.Printf("Number of times flush has been invoked: %d\n", stats.Flushed)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of times workers committed reqs: %d\n", stats.Committed)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of requests indexed            : %d\n", stats.Indexed)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of requests reported as created: %d\n", stats.Created)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of requests reported as updated: %d\n", stats.Updated)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of requests reported as success: %d\n", stats.Succeeded)
                    fmt.Printf("Number of requests reported as failed : %d\n", stats.Failed)
```

This is the log that I got

```
Number of times flush has been invoked: 1
Number of times workers committed reqs: 0
Number of requests indexed            : 0
Number of requests reported as created: 0
Number of requests reported as updated: 0
Number of requests reported as success: 0
Number of requests reported as failed : 0
```

I don't know why the result is 0. I am not sure how to find where the error is. Does anyone know how to find the error?

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking.  There are six stats at zero and it is a perfectly reasonable result to get back from the query shown.  What is the problem you need to understand?

Comment: The data is not inserted into elastic search, if there are some data inserted, then the result shouldn't be zero. I am not sure what the error is.

Comment: You don't show your code for the data insertion but you are saying that's where the error is.  So it's impossible for anyone else to say what the problem might be with it ....